# Keycloak how to obtain RPT

Tags: token, keycloak

I'm trying to fetch all the permissions from Keycloak, ie all resources and scopes that a user has access to.

Basically, I want to fetch an RPT from Keycloak, with permissions shown as on [Keycloak REST API docs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/15.0/rest-api/index.html#_client_role_mappings_resource) and the below image

[image]

Unfortunately, the docs are either confusing, or the way of Requesting a RPT isn't shown. This example is all under RPT, and moving on, the docs just explain how to further introspect the token.

How can you obtain this token (anything that contains the permissions like in the sample token actually) from Keycloak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try something like this:

```sh
USER=test
PASS=test
CLIENT_ID=test
CLIENT_SECRET=your-client-secret

RESULT=`curl -s --data "grant_type=password&client_id=${CLIENT}&client_secret=${CLIENT_SECRET}&username=${USER}&password=${PASS}" http://localhost:8080/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token`
ACCESS_TOKEN=`echo $RESULT | jq -r .access_token`

RPT_RESULT=`curl -s -H "Authorization: Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}" --data "grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:uma-ticket&client_id=${CLIENT}&audience=${CLIENT}" http://localhost:8080/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token`
echo $RPT_RESULT | jq -r .access_token | cut -d "." -f2 | base64 -d | jq
```

This retrieves an access token first and then queries an RPT.

This should give you an output like this:

```json
{
  "exp": 1643134734,
  "iat": 1643134674,
  "jti": "f60caba8-8f20-43f0-9054-6389f998032c",
  "iss": "http://localhost:8080/realms/master",
  "aud": "test",
  "sub": "18cce3e6-e3a0-4be9-a1ff-6635adf5928b",
  "typ": "Bearer",
  "azp": "test",
  "session_state": "539a81bf-aa27-4ce4-911a-405f5a2c90ac",
  "acr": "1",
  "realm_access": {
    "roles": [
      "create-realm",
      "default-roles-master",
      "offline_access",
      "admin",
      "uma_authorization"
    ]
  },
  "resource_access": {
    "master-realm": {
      "roles": [
        "view-identity-providers",
        "view-realm",
        "manage-identity-providers",
        "impersonation",
        "create-client",
        "manage-users",
        "query-realms",
        "view-authorization",
        "query-clients",
        "query-users",
        "manage-events",
        "manage-realm",
        "view-events",
        "view-users",
        "view-clients",
        "manage-authorization",
        "manage-clients",
        "query-groups"
      ]
    },
    "account": {
      "roles": [
        "manage-account",
        "manage-account-links",
        "view-profile"
      ]
    },
    "test-realm-realm": {
      "roles": [
        "view-identity-providers",
        "view-realm",
        "manage-identity-providers",
        "impersonation",
        "create-client",
        "manage-users",
        "query-realms",
        "view-authorization",
        "query-clients",
        "query-users",
        "manage-events",
        "manage-realm",
        "view-events",
        "view-users",
        "view-clients",
        "manage-authorization",
        "manage-clients",
        "query-groups"
      ]
    }
  },
  "authorization": {
    "permissions": [
      {
        "rsid": "9f708183-5aa3-4a8a-96fd-5be9aef5427d",
        "rsname": "Default Resource"
      }
    ]
  },
  "scope": "profile email",
  "sid": "539a81bf-aa27-4ce4-911a-405f5a2c90ac",
  "email_verified": false,
  "preferred_username": "admin"
}
```

Comment: If the front-end client is already authenticated, do we need to do a token exchange or ask for user name again for this RPT token?

Is there a chance to use the access token already issued to public client?